# 'dnf list' shows Wine packages that can't be removed

Tags: fedora, gnome, wine, dnf, uninstall

I'm currently trying to uninstall Wine from my Fedora system using `dnf`, and while I seem to have been mostly successful, I'm still noticing a few packages that I can't seem to remove.

Running `dnf list | grep wine` shows about a dozen helper utilities for Wine and their versions:

```
wine.i686 7.12-2.fc35 updates
wine.x86_64 7.12-2.fc35 updates
wine-alsa.i686 7.12-2.fc35 updates
wine-alsa.x86_64 7.12-2.fc35 updates
wine-arial-fonts.noarch 7.12-2.fc35 updates
wine-capi.i686 6.16-1.fc35 fedora
wine-capi.x86_64 6.16-1.fc35 fedora
...and so on
```

Yet when I try to remove any of these packages (say, `wine.i686`) with `dnf remove`, I get a "no match for argument" error.

Additionally, I can still see some of these Wine packages in my Applications display (using GNOME, and clicking the 9 dots on my dock, I see a folder that appears to have several apps with the default icon, but is actually empty once opened. This folder used to contain 9 or 10 Wine utilities.)

I've already deleted the `.wine` folder in my home dir and run `dnf remove wine` successfully.

How can I get rid of these remaining Wine packages and the ghost apps in that folder?

Thanks in advance,
-Robbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dnf list
```

lists *available* packages, it isn’t limited to installed packages.

To list installed packages matching `wine`, run

```
dnf list --installed '*wine*'
```

If any are shown by the latter command, you should be able to uninstall them. If no packages match, you’ll see

```
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

instead.